# Array of data should be there in the variable even after deleting it from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I am assigning slots to two variables, but when I delete slots using one variable, data gets deleted from another variable as well. I want to keep data in other variable. Please help!

```
slot_list = banner_slots = slots.where(:slot_datetime => date_begin..(startdate - 2.minutes))
banner_slots.delete_all
p slot_list
```

But its returning an empty array `#<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation []>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby use reference to store variables. So, actually `slot_list` and `banner_slots` all point to same reference. Once one variable deleted, the other lost reference as well.

Normally, to keep the variable you need to clone.

```
> a = 'foo'
> b = a
> c = a.clone

> a = 'bar'
> b
# 'bar'
> c
# 'foo'
```

You can also use clone on `ActiveRecord::Relation` object.

```
banner_slots = slots.where(foo: 'bar')
slot_list = banner_slots.clone
banner_slots.delete_all
> slot_list
# will return records EVEN WITH ID!
```

**USE THIS WITH CAUTION**. This is not intended behaviour of ActiveRecord objects. When you delete a series of objects, it means they got **DELETED IN DB**. So the remained `slot_list` with ids actually **means nothing but some attributes**. They can no more represent db data.

I just explain why you saw that and introduce `clone`. Even it may do the trick, I **do not recommend you to do that**. Instead try another way.